# Sed add a word at the end of a line with \n

Tags: bash, sed, newline

I have a file structured like this:

```
word1 word2 word3
word4 word5 word6
```

and I use the command

```
sed -i '1s/$/word7/' file
```

to add the word "word7" at the end of the first line

The problem is that the word is not added at the end of first line, it's added like that:

```
word1 word2 word3
word7
word4 word5 word6
```

BUT when I run a 'wc -l file' command the number of lines of my file hasn't changed (it's still 2)!

I'm thinking maybe this is a problem with how the file was created, it was created by a C program with this kind of syntax:

```
fprintf(file, "word1 word2 word3 \n");
```

I can't re-run my C program, so what bash command should I run to get:

```
word1 word2 word3 word7
word4 word5 word6
```

?

Comment: IMHO you miss a space before word7.  The rest works for me as expected.  Please try a `hexdump` or a `od -xa` on the result.

Comment: I tried with the space and it still doesn't work. How do I use hexdex exactly? Other "funny" fact: if I open my file manually, modify it and save it, the 'wc -l file' gives me 0 lines!

Comment: @Sullivan Orlean:
for hexdump use `hd -c file`

Comment: you could also do a : `cat -v file` , which is often enough to see the special chars (but may be not enough sometimes). The problem is probably when generating the file : the "\n" of the server's C compiler may be different than a "\n" on the machine you use sed on. Try seing each servers `LC_LANG` values.

Comment: I don't know who deleted the answer below where all the information for the solution was! My problem was that my file had Windows endline characters, that I could see with the command 'file myFile'. All I had to do was a 'dos2unix myFile' command to get sed working correctly

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the end-of-line convention in your input file and what sed expects are different. Your input file uses the DOS end-of-line convention, where the end of a line is marked with the 2-byte sequence `0x0d 0x0a`. In contrast, sed expects the UNIX 1-byte convention `0x0a`. In former days `0x0d` actually meant 'carriage return' and `0x0a` meant 'go one line down'.

So when you run `sed`, it only replaces the one byte `0x0a`, leaving the non-printable carriage return `0x0d`.

I would recommend to delete all carriage return bytes by doing

```
tr -d '\r' < file_DOS > file_UNIX
```

and then proceed as before. Note that if your words contain non-printable characters, this could mess up your data.